# Django: Can I use objects.filter() for generic foreignkey?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, generic-foreign-key

**symbol.py**

```
class Symbol(BaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30,)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class StockSymbol(Symbol):
    market = models.CharField(max_length=10,)
    my_daily_price = GenericRelation(MyDailyPrice)
```

**daily_price.py**

```
class DailyPrice(BaseModel):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class MyDailyPrice(DailyPrice):
    open = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=15,
        decimal_places=2,
    )
```

What I want to do is,

```
symbol = StockSymbol.objects.first()
MyDailyPrice.objects.filter(content_object=symbol)
```

But it occured errors:

```
FieldError: Field 'content_object' does not generate an automatic reverse relation and therefore cannot be used for reverse querying. If it is a GenericForeignKey, consider adding a GenericRelation.
```

`StockSymbol` already has `GenericRelation`. What's wrong with it?

Or do I have to override `ojbect manager`?

Answer (score 12):

You can filter with `content_type` and `object_id`, instead of `content_object`.

```
from django.contrib.admin.options import get_content_type_for_model
symbol = StockSymbol.objects.first()
MyDailyPrice.objects.filter(content_type=get_content_type_for_model(symbol), object_id=symbol.pk)
```

Comment: Does anyone know why Django doesn't just offer to do exactly that for you?  I don't get it...

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped up @Akash's answer in a method to be added to a custom Manager or QuerySet:

```
def gfks(self, **kwargs):
    filters = {}
    for field, obj in kwargs.items():
        gfk = self.model._meta.get_field(field)
        filters[gfk.ct_field] = ContentType.objects.get_for_model( obj )
        filters[gfk.fk_field] = obj.pk
    return self.filter(**filters)
```

For example, if you had a model called `Comparison` with two GFKs called `product1` and `product2`, and added this method, usage would look like:

```
comp = Comparison.objects.gfks(product1=foo, product2=bar)
```

Would be nice if Django's contenttypes app provided some similar sugar automatically, but I'll settle for adding this to my BaseQuerySet class in the meantime.